How to fix- error: incomplete escape \U at position 28
I am trying to install ultralytics in my anaconda environment through :conda install -c conda-forge ultralytics.
However the following error shows when running these codes:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('conda', 'install conda-forge::ultralytics')

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2456, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2454     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2455 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2456     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2458 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2459 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2460 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2461 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:30, in is_conda_environment.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     25 if not Path(sys.prefix, "conda-meta", "history").exists():
     26     raise ValueError(
     27         "The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  "
     28         "Please use ``%pip install`` instead."
     29     )
---> 30 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:128, in PackagingMagics.conda(self, line)
    120 @line_magic
    121 @is_conda_environment
    122 def conda(self, line):
    123     """Run the conda package manager within the current kernel.
    124 
    125     Usage:
    126       %conda install [pkgs]
    127     """
--> 128     conda = _get_conda_like_executable("conda")
    129     self._run_command(conda, line)

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:53, in _get_conda_like_executable(command)
     50 # Otherwise, attempt to extract the executable from conda history.
     51 # This applies in any conda environment.
     52 history = Path(sys.prefix, "conda-meta", "history").read_text(encoding="utf-8")
---> 53 match = re.search(
     54     rf"^#\s*cmd:\s*(?P<command>.*{executable})\s[create|install]",
     55     history,
     56     flags=re.MULTILINE,
     57 )
     58 if match:
     59     return match.groupdict()["command"]

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\__init__.py:176, in search(pattern, string, flags)
    173 def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    174     """Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    175     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 176     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\__init__.py:294, in _compile(pattern, flags)
    288     import warnings
    289     warnings.warn("The re.TEMPLATE/re.T flag is deprecated "
    290               "as it is an undocumented flag "
    291               "without an obvious purpose. "
    292               "Don't use it.",
    293               DeprecationWarning)
--> 294 p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)
    295 if not (flags & DEBUG):
    296     if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
    297         # Drop the oldest item

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_compiler.py:745, in compile(p, flags)
    743 if isstring(p):
    744     pattern = p
--> 745     p = _parser.parse(p, flags)
    746 else:
    747     pattern = None

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:989, in parse(str, flags, state)
    986 state.flags = flags
    987 state.str = str
--> 989 p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    990 p.state.flags = fix_flags(str, p.state.flags)
    992 if source.next is not None:

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:464, in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    462 start = source.tell()
    463 while True:
--> 464     itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
    465                        not nested and not items))
    466     if not sourcematch("|"):
    467         break

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:872, in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    869     group = None
    870 sub_verbose = ((verbose or (add_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE)) and
    871                not (del_flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE))
--> 872 p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
    873 if not source.match(")"):
    874     raise source.error("missing ), unterminated subpattern",
    875                        source.tell() - start)

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:464, in _parse_sub(source, state, verbose, nested)
    462 start = source.tell()
    463 while True:
--> 464     itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
    465                        not nested and not items))
    466     if not sourcematch("|"):
    467         break

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:548, in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    545         continue
    547 if this[0] == "\\":
--> 548     code = _escape(source, this, state)
    549     subpatternappend(code)
    551 elif this not in SPECIAL_CHARS:

File ~\anaconda2.0\envs\opencv\Lib\re\_parser.py:402, in _escape(source, escape, state)
    400 escape += source.getwhile(8, HEXDIGITS)
    401 if len(escape) != 10:
--> 402     raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
    403 c = int(escape[2:], 16)
    404 chr(c) # raise ValueError for invalid code

error: incomplete escape \U at position 28

I tried using conda install conda-forge::ultralytics and using conda install -c pytorch -c nvidia -c conda-forge pytorch torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.8 ultralytics.
Is there any alternative way to install ultralytics I am using anaconda version 1.12.3 and python version 3.11.8
When I use pip install ultralytics I get No matching distribution found for ultralytics error.
I hope you can help as I am a novice, thank you!
